Co-ordinate ascent update for $B$
I want to solve the optimization problem by getting the update step for:
$\tilde{B} = \arg \max_{B} \{-\text{tr}(M^{T}M \Omega) + \sum_{j=1}^{p} \sum_{k=1}^{q} \text{pen}(\beta_{jk}|\theta)\}$ where $M^{nh \times q} = \begin{bmatrix}
           \Psi(\Theta_1)-\mathbb{X}_1 B \\
           \vdots \\
           \Psi(\Theta_n)-\mathbb{X}_n B
         \end{bmatrix}$
Here each $\mathbb{X}_j$ is a matrix of dimension $h \times p$ and $B^{p \times q} = (\beta_{jk})$. The part involving $\Psi(\Theta_j)$ is a $h \times q$ matrix which is devoid of $B$.
Now, $\text{pen}(\beta_{jk}|\theta) = -\lambda_1 |\beta_{jk}| + \log \left(\frac{p^{*}(\beta_{jk},\theta)}{p^{*}(0,\theta)} \right)$ and $p^{*}(x,\theta) = \frac{\theta \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 |x|}}{\theta \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 |x|}+(1-\theta)\lambda_0 e^{-\lambda_0 |x|}}$ where $\lambda_0,\lambda_1$ are all constants.
Also, note that $\Omega^{q \times q}$ and $\mathbb{X}_j$ are devoid of or independent of $B$.
Now, I can just re-frame the maximization problem as:
$$\arg \max _{B} \sum_{j=1}^{n} -\text{tr}((\Psi(\Theta_j)-\mathbb{X}_j B)'(\Psi(\Theta_j)-\mathbb{X}_j B)\Omega) + \sum_{j,k} \text{pen}(\beta_{jk}|\theta)$$
Using the KKT conditions here, can anyone help me out here regarding what should be the update step for $\beta_{jk}$, if am looking for a co-ordinate ascent type strategy?

$
\def\bb{\mathbb}
\def\LL{\cal L}
\def\a{\alpha}  \def\b{\beta}
\def\g{\gamma}  \def\t{\theta}
\def\s{\sigma}  \def\l{\lambda}
\def\O{\Omega}
\def\o{{\tt1}}  \def\h{\odot}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}  \def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}  \def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\pen#1{\op{pen}\LR{#1}}
\def\abs#1{\op{abs}\LR{#1}}
\def\sign#1{\op{sign}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\Si{\sum_i}  \def\Sj{\sum_j}  \def\Sk{\sum_k}
$The first ingredient that we need is the Frobenius $(:)$ product
which has the following properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \\
B:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
\LR{XY}:B &= X:\LR{BY^T} \;=\; Y:\LR{X^TB} \\
\LR{C\h A}:B &= C:\LR{A\h B} \\
}$$
Use the variables
$$\eqalign{
W_k &= \Psi(\Theta_k),
 \q Z={\O+\O^T}\!,
 \q Y_j = {X_jB-W_j},
 \q \c{H = {\Sj X_j^TY_j}} \\
}$$
to write a single component of the objective function and calculate its differential
$$\eqalign{
\phi_j &= \O:Y_j^TY_j \\
d\phi_j
 &= \O:\LR{Y_j^T\,dY_j + dY_j^T\,Y_j} \\
 &= \LR{\O+\O^T}:\LR{Y_j^T\,dY_j} \\
 &= Y_j\,Z:dY_j \\
 &= Y_j\,Z:\LR{X_j\:dB} \\
 &= X_j^TY_j\,Z:dB \\
}$$
Next, let's simplify the $\pen{\t|x}$ function before applying it to a matrix argument.
Define some more variables
$$\eqalign{
\rho &= \frac{\l_0}{\l_1},\qq \s=\l_1-\l_0,\qq \tau=\frac{\o-\t}\t \\
}$$
and use them to write the $\op{pen}\ {\rm and}\ \op{p}^*$ functions
$$\eqalign{
\op{p}^*\!\LR{x\,|\,\t} &= \frac{\o}{\o+\rho\tau\exp(\s|x|)} \\
\op{pen}\LR{x\,|\,\t}
  &= \log\!\lR{\o+\rho\tau}-\log\!\lR{\o+\rho\tau\exp(\s|x|)}-\l_1|x|
\\
}$$
Next, look at some elementwise matrix functions
$\big(\h\!/\!\oslash\:$ denote elementwise multiplication/division $\big)$
$$\eqalign{
S &= \sign B &\qiq S\h S = J\q\{ {\sf All\ ones\ matrix} \} \\
A &= \abs B \:\equiv\: S\h B &\qiq S\h A=B \\
E &= \exp(\s A) \\
F &= J\oslash\LR{J+\rho\tau E} \\
}$$
and recall how to calculate the differential of such functions
$$\eqalign{
dA &= S\h dB \\
dE &= E\h\LR{\s\:dA} = \s E\h S\h dB \\
d\log(X) &= dX\oslash X \q \{ {\sf Elementwise\ division}  \} \\
}$$
Let's calculate the differential of the
elementwise $\op{pen}$ function
$$\eqalign{
P &= \op{pen}\LR{B\,|\,\t} \\
  &= \log\!\lR{(\o+\rho\tau)\,J}-\log\!\lR{J+\rho\tau E}-\l_1 A \\
dP
 &= 0 - \LR{\rho\tau\:dE}\oslash\LR{J+\rho\tau E} - \l_1\,dA \\
 &= -{\rho\tau\:F}\h dE - \l_1\,dA \\
 &= -\lR{{\rho\s\tau\:F}\h E\h S + \l_1\,S} \h dB \\
}$$
Finally, write the objective function and calculate the gradient wrt $B$
$$\eqalign{
\LL &= -J:P \;-\; \Sj \phi_j \\
d\LL
 &= -J:dP \;-\; \Sj d\phi_j \\
 &= J:\lR{{\rho\s\tau\:F}\h E\h S+\l_1 S} \h dB
\;-\; \CLR{\Sj X_j^TY_j}Z:dB \\
 &= \lR{{\rho\s\tau\:F}\h E\h S+\l_1 S}:dB \;-\; \c{H}Z:dB \\
\grad{\LL}{B}
 &= \lR{{\rho\s\tau\:F}\h E\h S+\l_1 S} \;-\; HZ \\
}$$
Use this gradient in your favorite gradient descent/ascent algorithm to find the optimal $B$.

Thank you @greg for the detailed explanation!
